# SQL eliminate all duplicate entries when one entry fails to meet criteria

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I have 3 tables: recipe, ingredientlist and ingredients.

I want to select the names of all recipes that do not contain any meat ingredients.

recipe and ingredientlist have a `recipeid` attribute, ingredientlist and ingredients have an `ingredientid` attribute.

If `ingredientlist.ingredientid` contains any entries where `ingredient="meat"`, I want to exclude all `recipe.name` entries related to that `ingredientid`

I don't know how to write it, but here is my select:

```
SELECT recipe.name FROM recipe
INNER JOIN ingredientlist ON recipe.recipeid = ingredientlist.recipeid
INNER JOIN ingredients ON ingredientlist.ingredientid = ingredients.ingredientid
WHERE NOT ingredients.type="beef"
GROUP BY recipe.name;
```

Comment: If i could even just know the correct keyword I could figure it out

Comment: So is IngredientList the ingredient table that has the foreign key to recipes, and your Ingredients table, is actually a list of all ingredients without a key to recipe?

Comment: IngredientList contains foreign key IngredientId to Ingredients
Ingredients contains recipeID also in Recipe

ingredients contains all ingredient types (beef, chicken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Recipe R
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT * FROM IngredientList IL
                    INNER JOIN Ingredients I
                        ON I.ingredientid = IL.ingredientid
                    WHERE IL.RecipeId = R.RecipeId
                    AND I.type = 'beef')
```